# Ubuntu Budgie on Macbook air 2013, no WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, support

So when trying Ubuntu Budgie on this, the WiFi doesn’t automatically install, I have to go to Additional Drivers and tell it to use the proprietary driver. No problem there. So then I install and tell it to install 3rd party drivers (while connected to WiFi) and then I boot and there is no WiFi. So I go back to Additional Drivers and tell it to use the proprietary one again, but this time it tells me that I cannot download packages while offline! It worked a minute ago and I cannot get online without doing this…

No Ethernet jack on a macbook air, so if I can’t get this working I’ll have to go with another distro…

I posted this on Budgie forums too, but there is more traffic here so I figure someone here may know a solution.  I did find some info on this forum that seems to be getting me in the correct direction but I still have a roadblock or two.

If you have the installation USB or DVD, insert it and and drill down to: pool/restricted/b/bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool/main/d/dkms and drag dkms to you desktop.

Then install:
cd ~/Desktop

sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb

sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb

sudo modprobe wl

I try to install dkms and it says I need to have “make” installed. bcmwl is the wireless driver and needs dkms installed…

Comment: Can't you use a temporary USB tethering from your phone? Any smartphone will do.

Comment: And you probably want to take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Tethering is a GREAT idea!  I'll try it!

Comment: Tethering did the job.  Good idea.  Thank you!